# Design pattern for searching object in class of objects without comparing all objects in java

Tags: java

I want to search particular object in collection of class objects in java without comparing all attributes and all objects. I have individual attributes value in search key.

One of the way could be to create HashMap of objects based on custom hashing function(key would be concatenated string of all attributes value like "attr1|attr2|attr3".

Is there any other better way of doing this in java?

Comment: `collection.stream().filter(matchingWith(SearchTerm)).findAny()`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8 then use streams:
This returns a collection with your search result

```
yourCollection.stream()
    .filter( it -> it.attr1.equals(keyAttr1) &&  it.attr2.equals(keyAttr2) && ...)
    .collect( Collectors.toList());
```

or if you just want to do something with all matching

```
yourCollection.stream()
    .filter( it -> it.attr1.equals(keyAttr1) &&  it.attr2.equals(keyAttr2) && ...)
    .forEach( it -> do something with it );
```

In lower versions you could implement a filter function yourself that takes a collection and a matcher function as an argument and loops through your collection and filters out the ones that return true from the matcher function.